# HTML file with Angularjs code coming up blank

Tags: angularjs

I am learning Angularjs. I have started with http://fastandfluid.com/publicdownloads/AngularJSIn60MinutesIsh_DanWahlin_May2013.pdf

Most of the tutorial examples worked fined until I dashed into the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body data-ng-app=''>   
<div data-ng-controller="simpleController" >
<ul>
  <li data-ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
<script src='angular.min.js'></script>
<script>
function simpleController($scope){      
    $scope.names = [ 
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}
        ];
}
</script>
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: which angular version you are using?

Comment: check my answer, I explained conceptulally why It was not working & how will it work if you make changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a controller with out creating a module. You have to create a module before handling the controller.

In older versions of Angular JS(<1.3) you can create a controller with out a module. But in later versions it is not possible.

Please have a look at the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15">      </script>
  </head>

  <body data-ng-app='myapp'>
    <div data-ng-controller="simpleController">
     <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="x in names">{{ x.name}}</li>
     </ul>
   </div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myapp', [])
 app.controller('simpleController', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = [{
    name: 'Jani',
    country: 'Norway'
  }, {
    name: 'Hege',
    country: 'Sweden'
  }, {
    name: 'Kai',
    country: 'Denmark'
  }];

});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

OR

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

 <body ng-app='myapp'>
  <ul ng-controller='simpleController'>
    <li ng-repeat='x in names'>{{x}}</li>
  </ul>

 <script>
  function simpleController($scope) {
    $scope.names = [{
      name: 'Jani',
      country: 'Norway'
    }, {
      name: 'Hege',
      country: 'Sweden'
    }, {
      name: 'Kai',
      country: 'Denmark'
    }];
  }

  simpleController.$inject = ['$scope'];
  angular.module('myapp', []).controller('simpleController', simpleController)
  </script>
```

Comment: this doesn't explain why OP's  question was not working\

Comment: Thanks Rajeshwar. Can you suggest some material which will help me conceptually understand Angularjs?

Comment: @pixelite did you understand by above answer? why it was not working?

Comment: @pankajparkar  _You are using a controller with out creating a module._ I take this statement as a sufficient explanation

Comment: @pixelite, i can share some links with you, if u can share u r email id.

Comment: @pixelite that is what your problem, and inorder to get it working you should do mentioned setting, he explained how it worked..anyway its all up to you..I'm thinking you are here to get things done, why was they are not working

Comment: In older versions of Angular JS(< 1.3) you can create a controller with out a module. But in new version it is not possible.

Old version > http://jsfiddle.net/viralpatel/aLDJJ/

Answer (score 1):

The better way to do is creating controllers.js for controller

```
<html ng-app='myapp'>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-ng-controller="simpleController" >
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="x in names">
      {{ x.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The logic in controllers.js should be with module:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', [])
 app.controller('simpleController', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = [{
    name: 'Jani',
    country: 'Norway'
  }, {
    name: 'Hege',
    country: 'Sweden'
  }, {
    name: 'Kai',
    country: 'Denmark'
  }];

});
```

Comment: check your src="angular.js" is there or not... I have edited my answer, you can use the src script.

Comment: I had included angular.js file in the directory. I guess the issue was with the version or not creating module. Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 1):

You problem is you are using **Angular 1.3+**

Your code will work with Lower Version of angular (lesser than 1.3), because you are using global function declaration, & the global function declaration is disabled by default in angular 1.3.

If you want to get your code Working you need to enable global controller function declaration while initializing angular.

**Config**

```
app.config($controllerProvider) {
  // Don't do this unless you *have* to
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
});
```

But this is not good practice to use global functions, you should us modular approach as angular do use it separate out code. Then do mention you module name in you `ng-app` directive like `ng-app="app"`

**Code**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('simpleController',simpleController)

function simpleController($scope) {
    $scope.names = [{
        name: 'Jani',
        country: 'Norway'
    }, {
        name: 'Hege',
        country: 'Sweden'
    }, {
        name: 'Kai',
        country: 'Denmark'
    }];
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body data-ng-app=''>
    <div data-ng-controller="simpleController">
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="x in names">
                {{ x.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for a detailed explanation. Unfortunately have accepted an answer. :) you can share the tutorial link on pixelweb3@gmail.com Appreciate your time and efforts. :)

Comment: @pixelite You are happy with get thing working here rather than you should know how it working..let it be, Thanks for appreciation :)

Comment: the answer i accepted also explains the how part; of-course not in as much detail as you did but that was sufficient for me. So your conclusion that I am not interested in the how part is not a valid one.

Comment: @pixelite yeah.Exactly

Comment: Do email me the learning materials on pixelweb3@gmail.com thanks.. :)